# Custom ReactJS component that respects 'valueLink'

Tags: data-binding, reactjs

I'm building a custom ReactJS component (A 'Select2' dropdown library wrapper) and want to implement support for the standard two-way binding helper with the 'valueLink' parameter.

However it appears the mixin to handle the 'valueLink' parameter only applies to standard components, not custom components.

Is there a way to have my component implement the standard valueLink behaviour automatically, or will I need to explicitly parse and implement this support myself (Potentially introducing bugs or odd behaviours that aren't present in the base library)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object returned from `this.linkState` when using the `LinkedStateMixin` has two relevant properties: `value` and `requestChange()`. Simply use those two properties as your value and change handler, respectively, just as if they had been passed to your custom component via `value` and `onChange`.

Here's an example of a composite component that wraps [a jQuery color picker](https://github.com/laktek/really-simple-color-picker); it works both with `valueLink` and with standard `value` and `onChange` properties. (To run the example, expand the "Show code snippet" then click "Run code snippet" at the bottom.)

```javascript
var ColorPicker = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div />;
  },

  getValueLink: function(props) {
    // Create an object that works just like the one
    // returned from `this.linkState` if we weren't passed
    // one; that way, we can always behave as if we're using
    // `valueLink`, even if we're using plain `value` and `onChange`.
    return props.valueLink || {
      value: props.value,
      requestChange: props.onChange
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var valueLink = this.getValueLink(this.props);

    jQuery(this.getDOMNode()).colorPicker({
      pickerDefault: valueLink.value,
      onColorChange: this.onColorChange
    });
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    var valueLink = this.getValueLink(nextProps);
    var node = jQuery(this.getDOMNode());
    node.val(valueLink.value);
    node.change();
  },

  onColorChange: function(id, color) {
    this.getValueLink(this.props).requestChange(color);
  }
});
```

```css
div.colorPicker-picker {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: url(https://raw.github.com/laktek/really-simple-color-picker/master/arrow.gif) no-repeat top right;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 16px;
}

div.colorPicker-palette {
  width: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #598FEF;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
  div.colorPicker_hexWrap {width: 100%; float:left }
  div.colorPicker_hexWrap label {font-size: 95%; color: #2F2F2F; margin: 5px 2px; width: 25%}
  div.colorPicker_hexWrap input {margin: 5px 2px; padding: 0; font-size: 95%; border: 1px solid #000; width: 65%; }

div.colorPicker-swatch {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/113308/dnd/jsfiddle/jquery.colorPicker.min.js"></script>

<p><strong>With valueLink</strong></p>
<div id="app1"></div>
<hr>
<p><strong>With value and onChange</strong></p>
<div id="app2"></div>

<script type="text/jsx">
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var ApplicationWithValueLink = React.createClass({
  mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],

  getInitialState: function() {
    return { color: "#FF0000" }
  },
  
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <span style={{color: this.state.color}}>My Color Picker</span>
          <button onClick={this.changeColor.bind(null, "#FF0000")}>Red</button>
          <button onClick={this.changeColor.bind(null, "#00FF00")}>Green</button>
          <button onClick={this.changeColor.bind(null, "#0000FF")}>Blue</button>
          <input type="text" valueLink={this.linkState("color")} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <ColorPicker valueLink={this.linkState("color")} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  
  changeColor: function(color) {
    this.setState({color: color});
  }
});

var ApplicationWithoutValueLink = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { color: "#FF0000" }
  },
  
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <span style={{color: this.state.color}}>My Color Picker</span>
          <button onClick={this.changeColor.bind(null, "#FF0000")}>Red</button>
          <button onClick={this.changeColor.bind(null, "#00FF00")}>Green</button>
          <button onClick={this.changeColor.bind(null, "#0000FF")}>Blue</button>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.color} onChange={this.changeColorText} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <ColorPicker value={this.state.color} onChange={this.changeColor} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },
  
  changeColor: function(color) {
    this.setState({color: color});
  },
  
  changeColorText: function(evt) {
    this.changeColor(evt.target.value);
  }
});

var ColorPicker = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div />
    );
  },
  
  getValueLink: function(props) {
    return props.valueLink || {
      value: props.value,
      requestChange: props.onChange
    };
  },
  
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var valueLink = this.getValueLink(this.props);

    jQuery(this.getDOMNode()).colorPicker({
      pickerDefault: valueLink.value,
      onColorChange: this.onColorChange
    });
  },
  
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    var valueLink = this.getValueLink(nextProps);
    var node = jQuery(this.getDOMNode());
    node.val(valueLink.value);
    node.change();
  },
  
  onColorChange: function(id, color) {
    this.getValueLink(this.props).requestChange(color);
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<ApplicationWithValueLink />, document.getElementById("app1"));
React.renderComponent(<ApplicationWithoutValueLink />, document.getElementById("app2"));
</script>
```